# Android XML pull parser slow, how to speed up?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I wrote an XML parser, using XmlPullParser, however it takes a lot of time to parse a few hundred lines of data.

Can you take a look at the code and tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
    case ONE:
            buffer.clear();
            xpp.setInput(responseBuffer[ONE], "UTF_8");
            // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
            eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("firstTag")) {
                        bufferA = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("secondTag")) {
                        bufferB = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("thirdTag")) {
                        bufferC = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("u")) {
                        bufferD = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                        bufferE = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                        bufferF = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("so")) {
                        bufferG = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("wei")) {
                        bufferH = xpp.nextText();
                    } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ter")) {
                        bufferI = xpp.nextText();
                    }
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG
                        && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("close")) {
                    buffer.add(new VisitInfo(
                            bufferA,
                            bufferB,
                            bufferC,
                            bufferD, bufferE,
                            bufferF, bufferG,
                            bufferH, bufferI));
                }
                eventType = xpp.next(); // move to next element
            }

            break;
```

I have three more parsers, based on this structure.
Thanks.

Comment: whcih tool did you use to find out it's slow? Try http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html to use traceview to see what exactly is slow.

Comment: Traceview, also it takes around 20 seconds to parse a few hundred lines of xml.

Comment: Are you sure it's the parser and not the reading of `responseBuffer` or the writing of the found objects to `buffer`?

Comment: Absolutely positive. I drilled down to xpp.nextText() and xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase().

Comment: Are all of the tags of the XML structure required for your purpose? If not, use skip(), it may save some time. Follow "Skip Tags You Don't Care About" in http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: @dev_android Thanks, will try that and report back.

Comment: Plz inform me the result.

Comment: Hi guys, Sorry for not responding. The web service I was using was closed down. I will now have to create a test project to resolve this issue. I am not very sure whether I am going to do that or not. If I do, I will post my findings here. For now, I am closing this question. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 1):

The XmlPullParser class is very slow to handle large XML files. For this goal I prefer to use [VDT-XML library](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/), [VTD-XML Benchmark](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/benchmark1.html).

In my case I have XML file with 66841 lines and you can look at my results:

Nexus 5 : 2055 millisec

Galaxy Note 4 : 2498 milisec

Short example of XML file

```
 <database name="products">
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">20</column>
            <column name="catName">Fruit</column>
        </table>
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">31</column>
            <column name="catName">Vegetables</column>
        </table>
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">45</column>
            <column name="catName">Rice</column>
        </table>
        <table name="category">
            <column name="catId">50</column>
            <column name="catName">Potatoes</column>
        </table>
</database>
```

Configuration of "build.gradle" file

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/vtd-xml.jar')
}
```

Source code example:

```
import com.ximpleware.AutoPilot;
import com.ximpleware.VTDGen;
import com.ximpleware.VTDNav;


String fileName = "products.xml";

VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();

if (vg.parseFile(fileName, true)) {

     VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
     AutoPilot table = new AutoPilot(vn);
     table.selectXPath("database/table");

     while (table.iterate()) {
        String tableName = vn.toString(vn.getAttrVal("name"));

        if (tableName.equals("category")) {
            AutoPilot column = new AutoPilot(vn);
            column.selectElement("column");

            while (column.iterate()) {
                 String text = vn.toNormalizedString(vn.getText());
                 String name = vn.toString(vn.getAttrVal("name"));

                 if (name.equals("catId")) {
                    Log.d("Category ID = " + text);
                 } else if (name.equals("catName")) {
                    Log.d("Category Name = " + text);
                 } 

            }
        }
     }
}
```

Result

```
Category ID = 20
Category Name = Fruit

Category ID = 31
Category Name = Vegetables

Category ID = 45
Category Name = Rice

Category ID = 50
Category Name = Potatoes
```

it works for me and hope it helps you.

Comment: A few of vtd record to string conversion is not necesary they can be improved to significantly improve performance ...